# Mongodb check if any string from array of strings is present another string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hey guys i have two collections of "ORDERS" and "DRIVERS"

The ORDER collection is like

```
_id:5f8e7d8084378609b2dca93f
user_id:"5f8465a777b1814c588521e2"
price:96
city:"Mumbai City"
totalCost:96
```

so here city comes from google map, means i just drag the marker in my google maps and it sets the city as "Mumbai City"

and the DRIVER collection is like

```
_id:5f84485b0933073435cdee30
name:"Ratnabh Kumar Rai"
password:"$2b$10$MSxPYKkdn7HbpjoYCgbg1.RewN5Q26CFxSVLrFqR6e.J4jSNd7G5."
city:[ 'Mumbai', 'Ahmednagar', 'Yavatmal', 'Warud', 'Umred' ]
status:1
```

where city is manually assigned by the admin

what i want is wanna filter out that whether city from my ORDERS collection is in the DRIVERS collection or not....what i was doing until now was

```
let driverCity = data.city; /////city is the driver city which i am sending from front-end/////
```

> so now driverCity=[ 'Mumbai', 'Ahmednagar', 'Yavatmal', 'Warud',
> 'Umred' ] and order city is still "Mumbai City"

```
let doc = await db
        .collection("orders")
        .find({
          $and: [
            { city: { $in: driverCity } },
          ],
        })
        .toArray();
```

but it checks for the exact element so if google would have set "Mumbai" instead of "Mumbai City" this would be perfect but now as i have "Mumbai city" what am i supposed to do ?

Anyway i could check if any string from driverCity array is present in order city or any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RegExp` (a regular expression) to match partial data in Mongo.

```
let doc = await db
.collection("orders")
.find({
  $and: [
    { city: new RegExp(driverCity,'i') },  // 'i' is for ignore case
  ],
})
.toArray();
```

You can also use regexp wildcards and control chars in case you want better control of what you're searching:

```
new RegExp(`^${driverCity}`,'i') // search cities starting with "Mumbai"
```

Or even add an optional `City` string in your search:

```
new RegExp(`^${driverCity}(\\s+City)$`,'i') // search either Mumbai or Mumbai City
```

Anyway, regex searches are considerably slower and could lead to imprecise results, so consider modifying the data that comes from Google before inserting it into the `orders` collection in a way that it will later match your driver-order searches.